# Application to Stream any Audio to UPnP Device (XBox 360)

Tags: audio, streaming, upnp

Is there any sort of application that will just take whatever audio happens to be playing on a PC and stream it to a UPnP Client?
For example, you could just run the app, and then play music from anything....WMP, iTunes, VLC, whatever...it would likely just use the Stereo Mix "device, and then on an XBox 360 you could connect to that stream and it would just play it back.

I know this should technically be possible... and I was thinking of trying to create something to do this, but I don't want to recreate something that already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your specific example of an Xbox 360, No, this is not possible.

While there may be software to stream audio output, the Xbox 360 is missing the software to accept this. It will allow you to stream audio and video files from a PC through either Windows Media Player 11/12 or Windows Media Center, but both of these access the files directly and do not access the audio stream of the PC. The built-in audio player on the Xbox will also only access local files on the hard drive or CD, so this would not work either.

Are there other devices you have in mind as well, or was the Xbox 360 your only thought?

Comment: I was just thinking UPnP compliant devices in general because there are a lot that have this.  Also...I already have an XBox, so I was hoping I could do this as a software only solution and avoid buying new hardware.

Comment: WDTV would be a good example.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com

It's even free, and it should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible! Try [Jamcast](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/Default.aspx), it has an option to stream your soundcard's output. It creates a virtual track on your Xbox 360 under Music/PC-NAME/Saved Playlists/Virtual Soundcard.

It's not free and windows only, but it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player 11 is capable of this.
[Article by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/howto/mp11/xbox360towmp11xp_stepbystep.aspx)

Comment: You missed the point... that requires a specific application to be all set up with a library of music that is then streamed to the xbox.  I want to have whatever I hear on the computer...from the browser, movies, system sounds, itunes..EVERYTHING.. to be streamed to the xbox.  This would me controlling what is playing through the PC...I just want to XBox to be a conduit for the audio.

Comment: Then no, this is not possible. The Xbox does not support streaming the audio output from a computer, only streaming audio and video files via windows Media Player 11/12 and Windows Media Center. Sure, it's technically possible to do what you want from a technology standpoint, but Microsoft has to build-in this functionality, and there's very little reason for them to.

Comment: It wouldn't be an Xbox issue. It's a Windows sound device issue. A piece of software would have to act as a virtual sound card device. Any audio sent to it would be streamed to the upnp device (xbox, etc) as a never ending audio track.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick break down of how I do it.

Install icecast server

- Icecast creates a server that your remote media player can "tune" into, like a streaming internet radio station, but for your local network.

Install Edcast

- Edcast listens to your computer software mixer output (what goes to the sound card) and sends it to your icecast server, so it will stream anything on the local machine.

Point your media player of choice on your local network to the icecast url, such as 192.168.1.2:8000/stream.ogg (to find your ip address in windows, fire up a command prompt and hit the old "ipconfig")

I don't have a PS3 or XB360, to my understanding both can play internet radio. But I use an old laptop on high quality external soundcard and foobar2000 with the upnp client (purely to point the client to icecast link), which works really nice, because any audio played on my desktop machine get streamed.. there's a small delay, but for music its fine.

Quick google search pulled up a good detailed tutorial http://www.poromenos.org/tutorials/icecast

Peace

Jim

Comment: edcast appears down?